# Could be the radius of convergence $0$ for EGF if $b_n > n!$ for $n>n_{0}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, generating-functions, divergent-series, formal-power-series

let $f (x)$ be exponential Generating function (**EGF**) has radius of convergence $r$ defined as:$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}b_{n}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ such that $b_n > n!$ for $n>n_{0}$

Could be the radius of convergence $0$  for exponential Generating function (**EGF**)  if $b_n > n!$ for $n>n_{0}$ ?.

Comment: Why not? E.g., $b_n=n^n n!$.

Comment: ok,see this answer for some OP , under the titled condition r lie in (0,1] not include 0 , this mixed me ,https://mathoverflow.net/a/289778/51189